# Set HR to be as long as text above it

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set HR length dynamically? I would like it to be as long as the text above it.

http://jsbin.com/dozedenogi

[image: sample]

```
<html>
<head><style>
    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;  padding: 10px;}
</style></head>
<body>
    <table class='rule level_1'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Lorem ipsum
            <hr>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
            <hr>
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An easier option is to get rid of the hr's, add divs with inline-block around the lines of text, and give the first one's a border-bottom.

Comment: I need to know if this is for html emails so I can answer it the correct way

Comment: this is for a web

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you should wrap your text and `<hr>` element in a `<div>` with `display: inline-block` CSS property to make the div as long as the text is.

For example:

```
<div style="display: inline-block">
  Lorem ipsum
  <hr>
</div>
```

Here is a working snippet with your code:

```html
<html>
<head><style>
    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    table, th, td { border: 1px solid black;  padding: 10px;}
</style></head>
<body>
    <table class='rule level_1'>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            Lorem ipsum
            <hr>
        </div>
        <br>

        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
            <hr>
        </div>
        <br>

        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cool. I tried this but without inline style and it did not work. That is it.

Comment: the div has to be inline-block to work? as by default <DIV> renders as block. if not inline-styles, then add a common class to those divs and style it in css

Comment: Your solution works well. I was close to this solution before posting this question but I did not specify that style and it did not work. Now it runs smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a better way, without using a HR.

```css
table span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

table span:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class='rule level_1'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
      <span>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
      <span>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it looks nice as well. But I have too many tables in a code already.

Answer (score 0):

HR can't do this, wrap the text in span and user border-bottom with padding bottom instead.

Answer (score 0):

hr could be avoided and turned into br or hidden and a border like can be drawn via background.

Result is similar to an underline with an hr look (color can be different from text too)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

td:first-line {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, lightgray 1px, black 2px, transparent 2px);
  line-height: ; /* reset this if needed see example next  */
}

td hr {/* hide hr if there */
  width: 0;
}
code {font-weight:bold;color:gray;}

.lh:first-line {line-height:3em;}
```

```html
<table class='rule level_1'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      hide <code>hr</code> below
      <hr> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <code>BR</code> might be used for the line-break
      <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td class="lh">
      <code>BR</code> used + line-height on <code>:first-line</code>
      <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```